# How to change dataframe Json structure if field does not exist?

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe from a csv file, and I want to structure it as a Json,  with a Pyspark dataframe schema:

```
root
|-- NpoId: string (nullable = true)
|-- Name: string (nullable = true)
|-- Url: string (nullable = true)
|-- City: string (nullable = true)
|-- Zip: string (nullable = true)
|-- lat: string (nullable = true)
|-- lon: string (nullable = true)
```

As this is how I want it to look as a Json:

```
"recipient": {
   "id": 123,
   "name": "John Doe",
   "url": "www.stackoverflow.com",
   "address": {
      "city": "Whatever",
      "postal_code": "12323-1234",
      "location": {
         "lat": -12.121323,
         "lon": 123.2131
      }
   }
}
```

If lat and lon values are null location should be like this: `"location": null`

I currently have this code on pyspark to restructure it:

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.withColumn('recipient', F.struct(
   F.col('NpoId').alias('id'),
   F.col('Name').alias('name'),
   F.col('Url').alias('url'),
   F.struct(
      F.col('City').alias('city'),
      F.col('Zip').alias('postal_code'),
      F.struct(
          F.col('lat'),
          F.col('lon'),
      ).alias('location')
   ).alias('address')
))
```

I want to avoid having:

```
"location": {
   "lat": null,
   "lon": null
}
```

Because this is going to fail with ElasticSearch Geo-point type schema. There is a way to remove those 'lat' and 'lon' values from the location when they are null in the same dataframe?

Comment: Filter before the struct : replace `my_dataframe.withColumn` with  `my_dataframe.where("lat is not null and lon is not null").withColumn`

Comment: Doing it twice? One with lat and lon is not null and another 1 to do it when is null, to keep also the other field values and doing F.col('location').lit(null), because I do not want to remove the cases when lat and lon are null... there is still other fields that I want to keep on that Json structure.

Comment: Ok, I see. I misunderstood the problem. With your current schema, you have to keep lat and long in location even if they are null. One solution could be to change location from struct to map !